# write a function that takes an array of objects as a parameter and returns an array of the objects' names. then, log that array to the console

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm working on javascript array and need to write a function that takes the first index of the array below and returns an array of the objects' names.

```
var animals = [
  { 
    name: 'murphy brown the dog',
    type: 'dog',
    age: 4,
    fav_toy: 'squeaky octopus'
  },
  { 
    name: 'mervin',
    type: 'cat',
    age: 1,
    fav_toy: 'catnip mouse'
  },
  { 
    name: 'peppercorn',
    type: 'cat',
    age: 3,
    fav_toy: 'lady bug pillow'
  },
  { 
    name: 'willa',
    type: 'cat',
    age: 4,
    fav_toy: 'jingle ball'
  },

]
```

Here's my function:

```
function getName(animals){
  console.log(animals[0]);
   return (animals[0]);
}
```

Comment: Your function does pretty much nothing so far, do some research about how javascript loops work before asking a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array#map` to return just the names from each object.

```js
var animals = [{name:"murphy brown the dog",type:"dog",age:4,fav_toy:"squeaky octopus"},{name:"mervin",type:"cat",age:1,fav_toy:"catnip mouse"},{name:"peppercorn",type:"cat",age:3,fav_toy:"lady bug pillow"},{name:"willa",type:"cat",age:4,fav_toy:"jingle ball"}],
    res = animals.map(v => v.name); // ---> return only the name value of each object
  
    console.log(res); //               ---> log the result to the console
```

Comment: I just wonder what's that so wrong in the answer, that worths to be downvoted?

Comment: nice way of solving this using ES6. Thanks.

Comment: @kinduser: When running this code, I get: 'Uncaught TypeError: animals.map is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:15'    I'm only six weeks into javascript, so pardon my ignorance, but what might this mean?

Comment: @LMessing Probably the animals variable is not an array.